# Go installer didn't install the Start menu group not SciTe

Tags: go

I have installed Go (1.14) using the official Windows installer and now I'm reading the Go book at
https://www.golang-book.com/books/intro/1. It says:

> For windows the installer will install the Scite text editor. You can open it by going to Start → All Programs → Go → Scite. You should see something like this:

In my case, going to Start and searching for SciTe doesn't bring anything up. Looking through the groups in the Start menu, there is not even one for Go.

`go` in the terminal works correctly.

Is the book out of date? Does Go no longer bundle SciTe with itself? Has my installer not done what it was supposed to?

I don't exactly need SciTe, I will use VS Code. I am just surprised to run into issues so early in the Go-learning process and would like to clear them out before proceeding.

Comment: Official Go distribution does not come with a text editor.

Comment: The go installer never included SciTE. Seeing how old the book is, it's probably outdated or incorrect in many other ways. Just start with the official documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To make the installation of this software easier an installer is
>   available at the book's website: http://www.golang-book.com/. This
>   installer will install the Go tool suite, setup environmental
>   variables and install a text editor.

---

As it says, it only applies to installs from the book's website, not the official Go websites.